# Formatting a date gives different values in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have the following javascript function

```
function dateFormatter(value) {     

    var d= new Date(value)
    console.log('value    : ' + value);
    console.log('d        : ' + d);
    var formattedDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' + ('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    console.log('formated : ' + formattedDate)
    return formattedDate
}
```

The value is a datetime from MS-SQL.

In IE/Edge I get the correct formatted value... here is a sample output from the console log...

```
value    : Oct  3 2016  8:00AM
d        : Mon Oct 03 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
formated : 2016-10-03 08:00

value    : Oct 31 2016  8:00AM
d        : Mon Oct 31 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
formated : 2016-10-31 08:00
```

In Chrome I get an error that the date is not valid...

```
value    : Oct  3 2016  8:00AM
d        : Invalid Date
formated : NaN-aN-aN aN:aN

value    : Oct 31 2016  8:00AM
d        : Invalid Date
formated : NaN-aN-aN aN:aN
```

Any ideas why this is... as I'm at a loss. The formatted value is output to a html table so in IE and Edge I get the desired value where as in Chrome each value is `NaN-aN-aN aN:aN`

Any help appreciated

Comment: Chrome is just refusing to parse that date format. Date parsing in JavaScript is not consistent between browsers, and that format you've got follows no common standard.

Comment: Use moment.js it will keep you sane. Also recommend using epoch timestamps in milliseconds instead of string based dates.

Comment: @Pointy The value is taken from a MS SQL field (datetime)... in SQL the first of the dates is stored as 2016-10-03 08:00:00.000. (a common standard I believe). In both IE and Chrome this date (value) output to the console give Oct  3 2016  8:00AM... from there on the two browsers behave differently one creating a date with new Date(value) the other not.

Comment: The value inside SQL Server is represented as a numeric timestamp. The string representation is just that - a rendering of the internal time value. The form `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" is accepted in Chrome, but it has to look like that, dashes and colons and everything.

Comment: @Darkrum... Thanks... have incorporated moments.js and can now do all sorts of things with Dates.

Comment: @Mych Good to hear. I still would how ever convert to storing epoch timestamps in milliseconds for dates and avoid string based. The later is prone to error across platforms.

Comment: @Darkrum I did think about this but the data is also being used by reporting services so that would mean a whole bunch of changes in the reports also to make the date data user-friendly.